# Url got replaced to a symbol

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, email

i've been working on reset password url, let me get straight to the point.
Here's my sample code that i'm working on. I believe it's working fine on apache. But i'm currently working on IIS Server.

```
$resl_url = base_url() . $this->controller . "/reset_by_link?reset_code=" . $random . "&u=" . $baris->usr_id . "&e=" . $enc_username;
$mail_data['reset_link'] = $resl_url;
```

it produce this url:

https://hris-id.tmf-group.com/ess_lenovo/login/auth/reset_by_link?reset_co=e=5T/BX1GRDU&u=2&e=lffdmdnhkjjogdmkkmkpibjbkefnjgbc

and this is the url that i expected to appear:

https://hris-id.tmf-group.com/ess_lenovo/login/auth/reset_by_link?reset_code=5T/BX1GRDU&u=2&e=lffdmdnhkjjogdmkkmkpibjbkefnjgbc

Note: this url is being sent by email.

Will appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: ie diff in  reset_co=e=  and   reset_code=. is it ?

Comment: @safinchacko yes, it seems like the problem is on codeigniter mail sending configuration. But i'm still looking for a solution to fix this :)

Comment: it is strange...Is your email working correctly ?

Comment: Yes, my email is working fine. But only some characters got replaced by some funny symbols/chars

Comment: Try to replicate the problem again. ie changing the random data.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, i found the solution. You need to tweak the codeigniter's email library. I'll post the answer later. :)